# Watson Assistant keeps resetting the conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm using Watson assistant service and in my dialogue I ask the user for a contact number (`@sys-number`) and then the address.

It works correctly in the "try it out" panel, but when I talk to it in my Telegram application it does not ask the user for the address.

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issue? If so please mark it answered.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common issue for people starting off coding for Watson Assistant.

Watson Assistant is stateless. This means every time you make a call to it, it does not know where it is unless you pass back the `context` object.

On your first calls response you will receive the `context` object. This has to be sent back to Watson Assistant on your next call, so it knows to move further in the conversation.

There are a number of SDK's that handle this for you.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud